# Sending Object through ObjectOutputStream is blocked

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have this Class in both my Client and my Server

```
public class user implements Serializable{
int pass;
String name;
public user(int pass, String name){
    this.pass = pass;
    this.name=name;
}//i also have a getPass and a getName
```

Here is how I setup the Streams

```
private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

    showMessage("\n The streams are now set up! \n");
}
```

Now what I want to do is send a user object from the client to the server
Here is what I do on the Client Side:

```
button1l.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){                
                if(isLogin(id)==true){
                    User user1 = new User(123,"test");
                    try {
                        output.writeObject(user1);
                        output.flush();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ClientClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    );
```

and on the server side:

```
 public void run()  {
        sendMessage("hello there\n");

        do{
            try{
                System.out.println("before\n");//everytime loop it reaches here
                User user1 = (User) input.readObject(); //but never here
                System.out.println("read user\n");
                System.out.println("x="+ user1.getPass()+ "y=" + user1.getName());
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
                System.out.println(classNotFoundException);//i just added this println

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClientThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }while(true);


    }
```

But nothing happens. No errors just a blank screen. So what am I doing wrong or is it the wrong way to do this??
PS: After adding the println(classNotFoundException); The print i get everytime i try to send is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: client.User ..

This is the program structure
[image]

Comment: `output.flush();` ***after*** `output.writeObject(user1);`

Comment: why would that change anything?

Comment: @Syarx The data may be buffered on the sender's side, calling `flush()` will force the system to send the buffer.

Comment: @Titus I tried it, nothing changed

Comment: In that case, the problem must be something else. Can you share more of your code ?

Comment: am i allowed to share github links?

Comment: Make sure you construct the `ObjectOutputStream` before the `ObjectInputStream`, at both ends. It isn't clear where you are blocking, or indeed whether an exception isn't being thrown and ignored. More code required. And what is the meaning of your title?

Comment: @EJP changing the order made the whole thing stop communicating at all. I added bigger chunks of the code if it helps

Comment: The `User` class is in different packages. In the server program is in the `server` package and in the client program is in the `client` package, it has to be in the same package in both programs in order for instances of this class to be considered the same kind of object.

Comment: @Titus But since they are different programs how can I have it in the same package?

Comment: I haven't expressed myself correctly. I meant to say that the class should be in a package with the same name on both the server and client programs. Because `server.User` is not the same class as `client.User`.

Comment: @Titus It works!!! Thank you very much. If you want can you rewrite this comment as an answer so this topic can be closed?

Comment: @Syarx If that was the problem there must have been an ignored exception. Changing the order to what I said won't stop it communicating, but ignoring exceptions will.

Comment: @EJP yeah it was that. Thanks for your help too, nice to see that not everybody here is rude... that has been my experience up until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `User` class is in different packages in the server and client programs.

In order for instances of this class to be considered similar objects, the class has to be in a package with the same name in both programs.